# Why noUiSlider not working in floating steps

Tags: html, nouislider

I'm using noUiSlider to select kilo meters. I want kilo meters like 250,500,1....30. But when i add floating numbers as step it doesn't work.

My code :

```
var priceSlider= $('#price-slider').noUiSlider({
        start: radius,
        connect: 'lower',
        step:0.25,
        range: {
             'min': 0,
             'max': 30
         }
        });
```

How i can use noUiSlider like the numbers

250,500,1,2,3....30 ?

Comment: noUiSlider hasn't been a jQuery plugin since 2016, and has since added support for several new device types (mostly touch and pointer based). I recommend you upgrade to the latest version, after which your configuration should mostly work.

Comment: can you help me to get the latest version of noUiSlider

Comment: You can get it from the documentation here: https://refreshless.com/nouislider/